# Fetch data only when a specific route loads and only once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to load data only once and only when a user visits a specific route. So in the following example only if a user visits the path '/' and only once per application refresh, a hook fetching data will fire and call the api. So if a user navigates from '/' to '/some_path' and goes back to '/' fetching won't occur again.

```
function App() {                                                                                                                                  
  return (                                                                                                                                        
    <Routes>                                                                                                                                      
      <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>                                                                                                       
        <Route                                                                                                                                    
          index
            element={
            <Suspense fallback={<Loading delay={1000}/>}>
              <HomeRoute /> 
            </Suspense>}/>
        <Route /*more routes*/ />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}

function Layout() {
  //If we fetch here we get only one api call, it dosen't matter
  //which route is called.
  const [data, setData] = useState(null) 
  useFetch('/', setData)
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <Sidebar />      
      <div className='routes'>
        <Outlet context={[data]} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function HomeRoute() {
  //If we fetch here we get an api call each time the HomeRoute is called,
  //and not only once per refresh. For example:
  //const [data, setData] = useState(null) 
  //useFetch('/', setData)
  return (...)
}
```